# Is there a performance impact using android:numColumns="auto_fit" in a GridView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-gridview

I've recently been refactoring some GridView layouts, after noticing that the adapter GetViews were being called multiple times. I found the following advice:

> [This will happen if your GridView is nested inside layouts that require several passes.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53733)

and through changing the views I have been able to reduce the number of calls.

Will the number of passes also be affected by having the number of columns set to 'auto_fit'? I have this at the moment to make sure the items always fit nicely on the screen. However, as the GridView can at times display a very large amount of data I want to make sure it is efficient as possible, so I could try and change it to use a fixed number of columns if there is a performance difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Afaik, there isn't really a performance hit. If you look at `GridView`'s source code for `AUTO_FIT` occurrences, you'll find the `determineColumns()` method being the most interesting. All it does is some basic arithmetic, which should have no noticeable impact on the overall performance. If you we're worrying about multiple layout passes etc, that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I did some more testing around this and it turns out you're right, it doesn't affect the layout passes or performance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing with various configurations I can confirm that there is no performance impact of using android:numColumns="auto_fit"